# Using arrays to read and display binary files

Tags: c, file-io

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main () 
{
    FILE *fp;
    int r, i;

    char fp_string [600] = "num1000.bin";

    fp = fopen(fp_string, "rb");

    for (i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        fread(&r, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
        printf("%d, ", r);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

This code currently reads and displays a binary file called `num1000.bin`, which contains 1000 random numbers. This code uses a `for` loop. How can I perform the exact same task but instead using an array?

Comment: You are using an array. fp_string is an array.

Comment: What do you want? It is unclear what you are asking. Do you want to use an array instead of the file, But if so do you want to have the bin file included. Be more precise...

Answer (score 1):

To define an array:

```
int r[1000];
```

To read 1000 files from your file, use [fread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread):

```
fread(r, sizeof(int), 1000, fp);
```

As you can see in the description of the `fread` function, one of its parameters specifies how many elements to read. Change it from 1 to 1000.

---

To display your numbers, you still need a loop.

```
for (i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
    printf("%d, ", r[i]);
}
```

Notice how it's now `r[i]` - because `r` is now an array that contains 1000 numbers, and not just one.

Answer (score 1):

Firslty you need to know the format of the random numbers. Presumably they are in native int format, but you need to check, especially since they are rnadom and so no commonsense testing is possible.

If you know that the number is exactly 1000, you can read in using fread

```
 int r[1000];
 fread(r, sizeof(int), 1000, fp);
```

But this is a bad habit. The data might end early. The format might be endian-reversed from native, or 16 or 64 bit instead of 32. You really need to get into the habit of reading binary data portably.